# Create a custom function in Python, to use an user data from df1 and with data from df2, determine the training level of the user

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if I am missing anything obvious or asking a silly question, I am just starting the adventure of data analyst and using python/panda and this adternoon things have been far from smooth.
Dont get me wrong, still happy and feel like I managed to achieve a lot, but this is something i cannot figure out.

I have df1:
[screenshot of df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPBGf.png)

and df2
[screenshot of df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hymog.png)

and for each User in df1, I need to find out their highest training level from df2. The problem is, that in df2, this same user can be listed multiple times, as they progress through the training.
I am trying to create a function where only the highest lev of training is returned with the date it has been completed, and after spending hours on it, i have not moved a step forward.

```
class colleague:
    def __init__(self, ID, name, surname, status):
       self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
    def updateTraining(self,level, date):
        if hasattr(self, 'level') == False:
            self.level = level
            self.trainingDate = date
        
    if level == 'Lev_3':
        self.level = 'Lev_3'
        self.trainingDate = date
    elif level == 'Lev_2':
        if self.level != 'Lev_3':
            self.level = level
            self.trainingDate = date
    elif level == 'Lev_1':
        if self.level != 'Lev_3' and self.level != 'Lev_2':
            self.level = level
            self.trainingDate = date

colleagueList = []
for ind in df1.index:
    colleagueList.append(colleague(df1['User Sys ID'][ind], df1['First Name'][ind], df1['Last Name'][ind], df1['Title'][ind]))
    

for person in colleagueList:
    dfPerson = df2[df2['User Sys ID'] == person.ID ]
    for assignment in dfPerson.index:
        person.updateTraining(dfPerson['Item ID'][assignment], dfPerson['Completion Date'][assignment])
    if hasattr(person, 'level'):
        print(person.ID, person.name, person.title, person.level, person.trainingDate)
```

The above does not return any faults but it also doesnt work. Literally nothing happens when i run this cell in jupyter notebook.
Why? Any suggestions?
a very desperate Data Analyst Beginner!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below would work.

Output:

[image]

I start with `df2`: Sort the dataframe by name and level - this will arrange the levels from high to low for each name. Then group same names together, and pull the first row from each group (each person). This will contain their highest level, as we've sorted levels from high to low per person.

Then I use the names in `df1` to see where they match in `df2`, and pull out the value from `highest_level` for the matching row.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['Active', 'Inactive'] * 2,
                    'Last Name': ['Smith', 'Khan', 'Malik', 'East'],
                    'First Name': ['John', 'Arun', 'Arif', 'Linda'],
                    })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item ID': ['Lev_1', 'Lev_1', 'Lev_2', 'Lev_2', 'Lev_2', 'Lev_2', 'Lev_3', 'Lev_3'],
                    'Completion Date': [f'0{i}/01/2023' for i in range(1, 9)],
                    'Last Name': ['Smith', 'Khan', 'Malik', 'East'] * 2,
                    'First Name': ['John', 'Arun', 'Arif', 'Linda'] * 2,
                    })


#In df2, add a column describing the highest level for each person
df2['highest_level'] = (
    df2
    #Sort by name, and within each name sort levels from high to low
    .sort_values(['Last Name', 'First Name', 'Item ID'], ascending=False)
    #Group by name
    .groupby(['Last Name', 'First Name'])
    #Return the first row of each group. This'll be the person's highest level.
    .transform('first')['Item ID']
)

#Add this info to each name in df1
df1['highest_level'] = df1[['Last Name', 'First Name']].apply(
    #For each row in this df1, find the rows where it matches df2 names,
    # and index into the highest level for that name, returing a single number 
    lambda x: df2.highest_level[ df2[['Last Name', 'First Name']].eq(x).all(axis=1) ].iloc[0],
    axis=1
)

display(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look into it.

i just run the code and im getting:

2single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" fault

Comment: Can you run it on the test data in the code? Perhaps it makes assumptions that are not valid for your data.